# How to set different url into <form>, using parameter

Tags: html, forms

I want to call different controllers, depending on `start` parameter:

(parameter `start` is boolean)

I am try to implement this task, using thymeleaf framework, but in this case him not working:

```
<div class="w3-container" align="center">
    <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="competition" type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for competitions.." title="Type in a competition name">
    <form th:if="${start}" action="/challenger" method="post">
    <form th:if="${!start}" action="/competition" method="post">
.............
........
        <input class="w3-button" type="submit" value="Go"/>
    </form>
    </form>
</div>
```

### How to accomplish this task in my case?

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of what you are trying to accomplish and what is happening with your current solution?

Comment: I calls this html page from different controllers and want call different url  depending on `start` parameter. Both controllers send to this page `start` parameter with different value. That all